# My Android application for a Facebook login wont open a session if I have Facebook App installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Im Working in a very simple app for Android. It is supposed to hit the market very soon. I have to make a login to facebook but it seems that the Facebook Application denies my app to login. I can't just uninstall the facebook app because its gonna be on Google Play on a few weeks, and of course i can't ask to the users to uninstall their Facebook App.

```
private void goFacebookLogin(){
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()){
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null){
                                fbButton.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session is not opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

That is the code im using.
So... how can I login with my facebook Application without having to uninstall Facebook App?

Comment: When you say "denies my app to login", what's the exact error you're seeing? A screenshot or a logcat output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook app should not interfere with your app logging in to Facebook. In fact, if the user has the latest Facebook Android app installed it provides useful native Dialogs. Try this code for logging in to Facebook:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()){
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback);
}else{
    session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
}
```

Where `statusCallback` is:

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
```

And the inner class `SessionStatusCallback` is defined as:

```
    protected class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened() && session != null){
            sessionChangedCallback();
        }
    }
}//end of SessionStatusCallback class
```

The method `sessionChangedCallback()` is where you want to put your code when the sessionstate changes. Leave your `onActivityResult()` code the same. And finally, remember to place this in your manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Try that code and see if it works. Like I said before having the Facebook app installed should not interfere with your apps ability to login to Facebook.

Comment: Does sessionChangedCallback() points to the regular login I do?

Comment: I actually ran into something I might be missing. I found that you have to change the default debug key to generate a new one. but I'm still working on it

Comment: I finally solved it. I was using JDK 1.7 so generate my Hash key. The solution is to download JDK 1.6_xx and generate a new Hask key with the keytool in it.